Segmentation fault err but add fprintf() not segmentation fault err

extern void *masu_malloc(size_t size);
extern void masu_free(void *ptr);
extern void *masu_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
extern void *masu_calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "masu_malloc called with size %zu\n", size);
    return masu_malloc(size);
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "masu_free called with ptr %p\n", ptr);
    masu_free(ptr);
}

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "masu_realloc called with ptr %p and size %zu\n", ptr, size);
    return masu_realloc(ptr, size);
}

void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    //fprintf(stderr, "masu_calloc called with nmemb * size %lu x %lu\n", nmemb, size);
    return masu_calloc(nmemb, size);
}

I am developing a dynamic memory allocator. After coding as shown above, I compiled it as below. Then, using LD_PRELOAD with my .so file, I ran a test
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall -Wextra
LDFLAGS=-shared
TARGET_LIB=libmasualloc.so
SOURCES=masualloc.c memlib.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
HEADERS=memlib.h

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET_LIB)

$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    const int num_allocations = 200000;
    void *ptrs[num_allocations];

    struct timespec start, end;
    long total_time;


    srand(time(NULL));


    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);


    for (int i = 0; i < num_allocations; i++) {
        size_t size = (rand() % (4096 - 32 + 1)) + 32; // 32~4096 바이트의 랜덤 크기 생성
        //printf("size: %zu\n", size); // size 출력
        ptrs[i] = malloc(size); // 랜덤 크기의 메모리 할당
        if (!ptrs[i]) {
            perror("malloc failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_allocations; i++) {

    }


    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);


    total_time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000L + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000L;


    printf("Time taken to perform %d malloc and free operations: %ld microseconds\n", num_allocations, total_time);

    return 0;
}

I tested this code using LD_PRELOAD=./myalloc.so ./test, but a segmentation fault error occurs. (startup error)
To debug, I added fprintf() statements to the frequently called functions. With these modifications, the test code runs without a segmentation fault error.
static void *mm_small_malloc(size_t asize)
{
    if (GET_ROOT(0) == NULL)
    {
        create_small_bin(CHUNKSIZE);
    }

    void *bp;
    void *ptr;
    printf("asize = %d\n", asize); //<-- this line

The occurrence of the error changes depending on whether the line commented with "this line" is present or not. This is not specific to a particular function but also happens in other frequently called functions.
Adding a delay to the code seems to make my algorithm work correctly.
Additional notes:

The only system call used in this code is sbrk().
The same result occurs even when running in single-thread mode with SINGLE_THREAD_MODE=1.


Redefining std library functions like malloc, free etc. is undefined behavior, and likely to cause trouble if you're linking stuff that uses the stdlib versions (eg: code from the stdlib). But run the code under an address sanitizer and see what's failing? It's very likely your allocator is buggy.

"I add a random printf and suddenly it works" looks exactly like you're writing something out-of-bounds, probably clobbering the stack.

As you're defining your own malloc() and friends DO NOT #include <stdlib.h> ... and, of course, do not call ANY function with a prototype in there (except if you redefine them).

Here's an example of the kind of problem you can have. Say your application calls strdup(). You'll call into libc, and I believe strdup() will call libc's malloc(), not yours. Then your application calls free() on the returned pointer, which calls into your free(). Bad things will happen. I assume that you'll have to define your own strdup() function.

@PaulHankin - what do you mean it's "undefined" behavior? There are lots of malloc/free replacement libraries out there, like hoard, that work fine.  But I agree that the OP's problem is almost certainly in their allocator, not in the code they shared.

@StreveFord Section 7.1.3 of the C standard says that using reserved names is undefined (and functions in stdlib.h are reserved). Which is not necessarily a show-stopper, because you can use non-standard documented behavior, but if I had a memory access problem with my allocator, I'd be testing it directly (with the masu_ names) to try to reproduce the bug first, before wading into getting into making sure the right functions are always being called at runtime.

Any function in the standard library (eg: malloc, free, realloc) is possibly a macro defined in their header, so if you include (either directly or indirectly) stdlib.h is potentially replaced by a macro which might call a function that's not called malloc (eg: _malloc) thus even if you get your symbols linked correctly, you might still find that the stdlib malloc gets called. This would cause havoc if for example causing some of you malloc calls to use the stdlib and others to use your functions.

When your code causes undefined behavior, it's common that the symptoms appear or disappear due to unrelated code like a printf being added.

@Streve Ford  Are there any other functions, besides strdup(), that need to be wrapped in a custom allocator implementation?

@KimTaeHyeon it is an unusual case, but here are a few others that I found: getline(), asprintf(), realpath(), glibc's getcwd(). There may be more. HOWEVER! I am no longer confident in my original comment. I looked at https://github.com/emeryberger/Hoard and did not see any "strdup". I did not spend much time looking at it. Maybe my analysis is wrong.

A bit more research seems to confirm my mistake. Even though both strdup and malloc are in libc, the call to malloc in strdup's code will get resolved at load time and therefore will call the preloaded malloc.
